# How does the V8 engine handle sequencing of added properties?

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

I've just been looking at the performance improvements in Google's V8 Javascript engine since I want to incorporate it into one of my own projects.

My interest at the moment is with the hidden classes. The basic idea is that V8 creates hidden classes as properties are added to an object so as to efficiently look up that property, avoiding a dictionary search.

For example, when you create a new `Point` object called `p`, it creates a hidden class `C0` which is a class with no properties and attach that class to the object:

[image]

The statement `p.x = 0` will modify the object to add the property, then create a *new* class `C1` specifying that the `x` property can be found at a specific offset within the object.

[image]

So getting at `p.x` after that is a relatively efficient operation.

Finally, executing `p.y = 0` will perform a similar operation, ending up with:

[image]

Now this is actually rather nifty since, if you create another `Point` object `p2`, no new hidden class needs to be created, it just gets "assigned" to `C0`. Similarly, adding the `x` and `y` properties in that order will also be efficient in terms of not having to create a new hidden class.

---

But I have two potential issues with this scheme. The first involves what happens with the following code segment:

```
Point p3 = new Point();
p3.y = 3141592653589;
p3.x = 2718281828459;
```

It seems to me that this would create two *new* hidden classes, one with `y` at offset zero and another with `y` at offset zero and `x` at offset one.

This seems a little space-inefficient as the final classes in both cases have an `x` and a `y` so should be able to share the class `C2`, albeit with the requirement that you would need to swap `x` and `y` in the object itself.

What would be the impact of making the transition map a little more controlled, such as ensuring properties are stored alphabetically? That way, whether you add `x` then `y`, or `y` then `x`, you would still end up at the same final class.

This would mean a little extra work when adding a property but could substantially reduce the number of hidden classes.

Or is that extra work likely to be a too much of a performance drain in itself?

---

The second potential issue is that, since the entire purpose of this scheme is to avoid a dictionary lookup on the object, how does moving the:

```
For x, see offset 0
For y, see offset 1
```

into the class help?

It appears to me that you will *still* need to lookup the property name in the hidden class to get the offset within the object.

Or am I missing something and no dictionary search of the class is required?

Comment: @Hanky, the last car I modified was a 1968 Holden HR, bored out the pistons to make them lighter than added a cap on top of each for more compression. Got it up to 90mph (from about 70) but the engine fused shortly after that. Modern cars are no fun at all, having to plug in an expensive and not-very-available computer to do anything with :-)

Comment: haha that must have felt nice :)

Comment: Maybe you'll find this helpful: http://www.google.com/patents/US8244775. Concerning your question of swapping x and y properties, I remember reading somewhere that v8 can handle such little inconsistencies right. But in general different hidden classes are produced. There's little point in implementing something like you suggested since almost always properties are added in the same order (through the same constructor function).

Comment: It's strange to use constructor and then do property assignments outside the constructor - unless you already did them in constructor then the order of the assignments doesn't matter (although in terms of CPU cache they could). Then the amount of extra hidden classes being created due to  same object having its properties assigned in different orders is marginal. Note that names of properties and their order is far from being the only determiner of the hidden class of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After optimization, no dictionary search is necessary (for most accesses).

At property access time, v8 has (hopefully) converted the property access to an inline cache stub.  This means that by the time `x` is being accessed, it's identity as `x` has been subsumed by the offset value.  So it's not really `x` on its face anymore, or even `x at offset 0`, it's just `offset 0`.  And even though the object representation is called a "map," it's really just an offset table.  This is what makes property accesses fast.

When it's time to add a new property, the question is not "where's an object with all the properties the current object has plus the new property?"  It's "for this object, what do I need to do to add this one property?" Transitions are selected on that basis.  In optimized code, names of existing properties are not taken into account.  Cutting out redundant hidden classes would require some relatively hefty operations to find a matching map.

Your supposition that reversing property additions creates two new hidden classes is right on.  You can get some insight on that by running the following with `d8 --allow-natives-syntax`:

```
function Point() {}

var p = new Point();

var px = new Point();
px.x = 0x10101;

var py = new Point();
py.y = 0x20202;

var pxy = new Point();
pxy.x = 0x30303;
pxy.y = 0x40404;

var pyx = new Point();
pyx.y = 0x50505;
pyx.x = 0x60606;

var newp = new Point();
checkmaps();
newp.x = 0x70707;
checkmaps();
newp.y = 0x80808;
checkmaps();

function checkmaps() {
  var sameas = [];
  if (%HaveSameMap(newp, p))
    sameas.push("p");
  if (%HaveSameMap(newp, px))
    sameas.push("px");
  if (%HaveSameMap(newp, py))
    sameas.push("py");
  if (%HaveSameMap(newp, pxy))
    sameas.push("pxy");
  if (%HaveSameMap(newp, pyx))
    sameas.push("pyx");
  print(sameas);
}
```

The output is:

```
p
px
pxy
```